# Java Scanner & Regex: Applying findWithinHorizon twice returns no results

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I have the following code, which objective is to detect the encoding/charset of a given webpage, using regular expressions.

I need to test two of the following regex (`regexHTML1` and `regexHTML2`). **In this case, the correct regex is the second one, `regexHTML2`**, which outputs:

```
Found: <meta id="HtmlHead1_desc" name="description" content="Televisores,TV 3D, TV, vídeo e MP3. Compre online Televisores,TV 3D na Fnac" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta
Found: UTF-8
```

With this code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.fnac.pt/imagem-e-som/TV-3D/Televisores/s21075?bl=HGAChead");
is = url.openStream();

String regexHTML1 = "<meta.*content=\\\".*;.*charset=(.*)\\\"\\s*/?>";
String regexHTML2 = "<meta.*content=\\\".*;.*charset=(.*)\\\"\\s*/?>\\s*<meta";

//  Scanner s = new Scanner(is);        
//  s.findWithinHorizon(regexHTML1, 0);
//  MatchResult result = s.match();
//  for (int i = 0; i <= result.groupCount(); i++)
//      System.out.println("Found: " + result.group(i));
//  s.close();

Scanner s2 = new Scanner(is);
s2.findWithinHorizon(regexHTML2, 0);
MatchResult result2 = s2.match();
for (int i = 0; i <= result2.groupCount(); i++)
    System.out.println("Found: " + result2.group(i));
s2.close();
```

However, if I uncomment the commented code block that tests the first regex (`regexHTML1`), the output is:

```
Found: <meta id="HtmlHead1_desc" name="description" content="Televisores,TV 3D, TV, vídeo e MP3. Compre online Televisores,TV 3D na Fnac" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="PICS-Label" content="(PICS-1.1 &quot;http://www.rsac.org/ratingsv01.html&quot; l gen true comment &quot;RSACi North America Server&quot; by &quot;webmaster@fnac.com&quot; for &quot;http://www.fnac.com/&quot; on &quot;1997.06.30T14:21-0500&quot; r (n 0 s 0 v 0 l 0))" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" /><link id="HtmlHead1_canonicalLink" rel="canonical" href="http://www.fnac.pt/imagem-e-som/TV-3D/Televisores/s21075" />
Found: UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="PICS-Label" content="(PICS-1.1 &quot;http://www.rsac.org/ratingsv01.html&quot; l gen true comment &quot;RSACi North America Server&quot; by &quot;webmaster@fnac.com&quot; for &quot;http://www.fnac.com/&quot; on &quot;1997.06.30T14:21-0500&quot; r (n 0 s 0 v 0 l 0))" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" /><link id="HtmlHead1_canonicalLink" rel="canonical" href="http://www.fnac.pt/imagem-e-som/TV-3D/Televisores/s21075
```

Since `regexHTML1` is not appropriate. But when testing `regexHTML2` (the correct one) it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match result available
```

**How is this possible?**
The `regexHTML2` only works when I'm not testing `regexHTML1`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input streams are consumed as they are read (i.e., they know their current position).  So because you are using the same stream, it gets consumed by the initial scanning operation and nothing is left for the second scanner.

Use two different streams, or download the entire stream into a `String` or something similar, and match against that.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, you're right. I downloaded the stream into a `String` using something similar to http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-string-in-java/ and it's really slow. It looks like opening multiple `InputStream`'s is much faster.

Comment: The speed difference is probably that the method returns immediately when a match is found. If you use the input stream directly, you will only download the portion of the file needed to successfully match your regex, which may be a very small amount.

Comment: I think you're right, because the match should always occur in the begining of the document. Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

may be it is something to do with inputStream, can you please check , using two input streams, is1 and is2.

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you. Nevertheless, it does not make any sense... How can I test **apply several regex using the same InputStream**?
I even wanted to use the same Scanner and MatchResult, so...

Comment: store it in string and then use ..as mentioned on comment by @BeeOnRope